# Linux to windows - Execute .exe remotely

Tags: powershell, centos, remote-access, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

We have requirement to execute .exe with parameters remotely from Linux machine to Windows 10. So we have installed PowerShell in CentOS. Following are the commands we used:

```
Invoke-Command -HostName abcdefg -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\sip\GetProcessInstance.exe" -$args[0] } -ArgumentList "http://hostname:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/listUserTasks?potentialOwner=abc@xyz.com"

Invoke-Command -HostName abcdefg -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\sip\GetProcessInstance.exe" -ArgumentList "http://hostname:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/listUserTasks?potentialOwner=abc@xyz.com" }

Invoke-Command -HostName abcdefg -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ }
```

Getting following error

> Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
>   At line:1 char:1

[image]

Same is working for Windows to Windows.

Comment: You cannot use `-Hostname` with `-Credential`. If you want to connect over SSH you'll have to use `-SSHConnection` parameter. [Check the examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you are trying to use invalid parameter set. Once you open [the documentation for `Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) you can find sets you can use.

Take a look at the block at the beginning of document I linked. There are only two possible sets with `-HostName` parameter:

```
Invoke-Command
      -ScriptBlock <scriptblock>
      -HostName <string[]>
      [-Port <int>]
      [-AsJob][-HideComputerName]
      [-UserName <string>]
      [-KeyFilePath <string>]
      [-SSHTransport]
      [-RemoteDebug][-InputObject <psobject>]
      [-ArgumentList <Object[]>]
      [<CommonParameters>]

Invoke-Command
      -FilePath <string>
      -HostName <string[]>
      [-Port <int>]
      [-AsJob]
      [-HideComputerName][-UserName <string>]
      [-KeyFilePath <string>]
      [-SSHTransport]
      [-RemoteDebug]
      [-InputObject <psobject>][-ArgumentList <Object[]>]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

As you can see, none of them has `-Credential` parameter available. Your options are:

1. Use `WinRM` instead of `SSH`

In this case you'll have to use `-ComputerName` param instead of `-HostName`

2. Use `-SSHConnection`

From the docs:

> This parameter takes an array of hashtables where each hashtable contains one or more connection parameters needed to establish a Secure Shell (SSH) connection (HostName, Port, UserName, KeyFilePath).

3. Use one of the sets I pasted above

As I don't have knowledge about your configuration I cannot tell you which one will suit you best so you have to choose yourself.

Comment: @robby- I used **-SSHConnection**   `$sshConnections = @{HostName="abcdefg"; UserName="domain\CI.Admin"; KeyFilePath="C:\Users\ci.admin\.ssh\id_rsa"}`     and used in  `invoke-command -SSHConnection $sshConnections -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\sip\GetProcessInstance.exe" -$args[0] } -ArgumentList "http://hostname:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/listUserTasks?potentialOwner=abc@xyz.com"`

Comment: @robby- Now i am getting  _ An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (bg-ci-sip:String) [], PSRemotingDataStructureException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken_

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons why this happened. I'd suggest you to try to troubleshoot it yourself (e.g check if you can use other cmdlets in remote session, check if the same happens on other machines in the network). Then you could post a new question regarding this error. By the way, if you feel that my answer resolved the issue in your question, please remember to mark it as accepted so others can find it easily.